# Compare Informatica exported XML for Workflow using VBScript

Tags: python, vbscript, informatica, informatica-powercenter

I have Informatica exported XML of Workflow. I need to compare two XMLs of workflow for changes within it.

How I can achieve it using VBScript/Python ? Can someone guide on this.

Comment: The problem is that objects are exported into XML in any order, so you can't compare it directly. You have to find a comparison key at every level of the XML to check if it exists in both files. You may prepare work by sorting the XML with a method like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14647638/xslt-sorting-how-to-sort-xml-childnodes-inside-a-parent-node-with-an-attribute
Note that there is a comparison utility inside the Workflow Designer, but it's not scriptable as far as I know.

Answer (score 0):

There's a iExportNormalizer plugin for Beyond Compare utility that will do that for you. It's available on [Informatica Marketplace](https://marketplace.informatica.com/solutions/iexportnormalizer) for free - but as said, you'll need the Beyond Compare, which isn't a freeware.